# So $k^2-\Delta: H_{s+2}\to H_{s}$ is a homeomorphism, but what does that tell us?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, intuition, examples-counterexamples, distribution-theory

For each $t\in\mathbb{R}$, we define the Sobolev space \begin{equation}
H_t=\{u\in\mathcal{S}':\int(1+|y|^2)^t|\hat{u}(y)|^2dy<+\infty\},
\end{equation} where $\mathcal{S}'$ is the space of tempered distributions on $\mathbb{R}^d$.

We give this space a norm \begin{equation}
\|u\|_t=(\int(1+|y|^2)^t|\hat{u}(y)|^2dy)^{1/2}.
\end{equation}

I learnt from [Rudin](http://books.google.com.hk/books/about/Functional_analysis.html?id=Sh_vAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y) that under these definitions the operator $k^2-\Delta$ is a homeomorphism from $H_{s+2}$ to $H_{s}$. This seems very interesting, but Rudin does not say how we can use this fact.

I wonder what can we learn from this. Any reference or suggestion is welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that the problem $$k^2-\Delta u=f$$ has solution for all $f\in H^s$.

Comment: @Tomás Well, but that only uses the fact that $k^2-\Delta$ is surjective.

Comment: THe solution is unique. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this problem is not that promising as I thought. I guess I will just answer it and close it.

As mentioned by Tomas. This implies the unique existence of solution to $(k^2-\Delta)u=f$.